# What roles would a six-man reconnaisance team need?

Tags: military

My current piece requires the main characters to travel towards an observation post that's manned by an XCOM/F.E.A.R.-style organisation on the edge of a S.T.A.L.K.E.R.-style disaster zone. The OP is mainly supposed to serve as a first contact point with the orcs who live in that area, but if the orcs could shed some light on some suspicious dwarven maritime traffic, that would be excellent...

The soldiers are drawn from what's essentially the British military in 1918, but I'm stumped on the roles and equipment required for this. I'd like to keep the numbers down to six (the size of a squad in Jagged Alliance 2), and as far as I can tell, it needs the following soldiers:

- Commander
- Scout/translator
- Radioman/signalman (keep the orcs from getting *too* hostile by calling for naval support)
- Designated marksman/sniper
- Grenadier/automatic rifleman
- Medic (a carrot to go with the radioman's stick)

Are these roles sensible for this purpose?

Comment: I would rather use: spy, pyro, bard, thaumatic theurge, sensor and assassin.

Comment: Could anyone shed some light on the downvote (and more importantly, what I could do to improve this?). For that matter, why the votes to close?

Comment: @Renan I'm trying to keep it closer to reality.

Comment: The roles will of course be those which the story needs. For example, you could have the young officer with a troubled past, the grizzled outdoors man, the slick city boy, the drifting assassin, the talkative guy, and the mysterious outsider. Or maybe the gung-ho sergeant, the witty corporal, the tracker with Indian ancestry, the two patriotic criminals and the adorable orphan. What pseudo-military ranks and specialties you assign to them is secondary, unless you are writing military fantasy, in which case I'd say one optio, one decanus, two speculatores evocati, one tiro and one conversor.

Comment: Would probably be cheaper and quicker and more reliable to just give the Orcs a truckload of stuff...than to send a squad and hope they can convince them [orcs] to play nice out of the goodness of their hearts. Presumably they know the terrain and threats, it's not the US Marine Corps, so your radio man is probably no good in a fight, do Orcs respect the red cross? if it's a combat patrol you send soldiers and support with specialists once secured. Not that small unit tactics were all that evolved in 1918.

Comment: @GiuPiete I had considered adding a note to explain why the orcs aren't being just given stuff (political interference). Though now that you mention it, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Philip Rowlands Could the medic also be a cleric - if the fear of any god lies in the orcs' vocabulary.

Comment: Start with the concept of a [Fire Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireteam) as your base and work up from there.

Answer (score 3):

- **Point**
  They're all scouts, but one specializes in going first. Light load, SMG or shotgun, trained in stealth.
- **Heavy Weapon/Security**
  Someone to react immediately if the point runs into trouble. From 1940 or so it might be a GPMG gunner, with 1918 tech possibly a LMG or another SMG.
- **Commander**
  Probably also concerned with map reading/navigation. Armed with a "standard" weapon like a rifle.
- **Medic**
  Depending on the setting, probably armed and without the red cross.
- Possibly **Commo**
  The problem is that 1918 radios are not very portable. A messenger pigeon or wigwag flags won't do. Perhaps another point man, so one can rotate back into the middle of the column.
- **Heavy Weapon/Rear Guard**
  Equipped like the other heavy weapon guy.

Note that I'm not proposing a designated grenadier. Everybody has a few hand grenades, and 1918 technology rifle grenades are probably not right for a patrol.

No sniper, either. Snipers can do recon, but their role and training is different. They sit in a hide and wait for the target. Ordinary 1918s-era rifles have enough range.

---

With 1970s-era weaponry there would be a clear distinction between the roles. Shotgun or SMG for the point, GPMGs (belt-fed, 7.62mm or so) or SAWs (belt-fed, 5.56mm or so) for the heavy weapons, assault rifles or carbines for the rest (again 5.56mm). And there might be a grenadier with a 40mm grenade launcher. With 1980s-era weaponry, it would definitely be SAWs and not GPMGs, and the grenade launcher would be under the barrel of an assault rifle.

With 1918-era weaponry, things look different. Assault rifles did not exist, and something like the [BAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1918_Browning_Automatic_Rifle) is probably too heavy for the medic and commander. It might be a good choice for the heavy weapons people, or the heavy weapons are more SMGs, with differences in the ammo loadout. That leaves an ordinary (bolt-action?) rifle for the rest, or SMGs. An SMG would have ammo compatibility with the point man, but it lacks the range of a proper rifle.

So you could have just SMGs and rifles, plus hand grenades.

Comment: This answer (and the question) are based on modern conceits. A 1918 era British platoon was built around a Lewis Gun squad (one gunner, assistant gunner and several riflemen carrying the extra ammunition), a rifle grenade squad (two grenadiers and several riflemen carrying extra rifle grenades), and a squad of "bombers", carrying rifles bur armed with canvas sacks of hand grenades for use in the trenches and destroying bunkers. Other armies had similar breakdowns, although using different weapons like the BAR or Chauchat.

Comment: @Thucydides, my answer describes a halfway-modern SOF patrol, which differs from an infantry squad of the same time. A 1918-era patrol should differ from ordinary riflemen as well.

Comment: A 1918 era patrol was made from what was available in 1918 era armies. German *Sturmtruppen* in 1918 were specially raised and equipped, and early form of "Special Forces". For an infantry patrol in the era, you might send just the riflemen, or you might send an entire platoon for a "trench raid". You could not send for a platoon of Rangers or Commandos to do the job, that was the next war....

Comment: @Thucydides, we're talking about a patrol into a land with *Orcs* and *Dwarves*, not Mahdists or Ashanti. So not the average British regiment ...

Comment: And I'm talking about a WWI era Imperial army layout, so British, Australians, Canadians, Indians... If the army was raised and equipped to fight *Orcs* and *Dwarves*, then it would likely be entirely different in composition from the ground up-maybe even looking more like Boer War era "Mounted Rifles" rather than WWI era 1918 formations.

Comment: @Thucydides, the OP seems to disagree with you.

Comment: The OP also explicitly stated the British Army in 1918, which does put hard constraints on the answer.